# Netbeans JLabel Icon/Text Does not Display when Project is Built

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, jlabel

in Netbeans, I am using Jlabels to display images and text within a JFrame. The Jlabels display correctly in the IDE, but when I run or build the project, some of the Jlabels don't show up(Labels that are added later on after the first few). To fix this problem I have to start all over again and add the images all at once. This sucks cause I went from 4 to 8 and now I need to add 20 more images. I really don't want to start all over again.

```
 private void initComponents() {

    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    javax.swing.JSeparator statusPanelSeparator = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    javax.swing.JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    javax.swing.JMenu helpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    javax.swing.JMenuItem aboutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    statusPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    statusMessageLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    statusAnimationLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    progressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    jLayeredPane2 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    PC = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    ALU = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    BC = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    DR = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    MUXB = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    MUXD = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    RF = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    IR = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    ID = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    bg = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    mainPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
    mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 800));
    mainPanel.setName("mainPanel"); // NOI18N
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(900, 900));

    statusPanelSeparator.setName("statusPanelSeparator"); // NOI18N

    org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(honors231.Honors231App.class).getContext().getResourceMap(Honors231View.class);
    jButton2.setText(resourceMap.getString("jButton2.text")); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setName("jButton2"); // NOI18N
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
    mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(3055, 3055, 3055)
            .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(305, 305, 305)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addContainerGap(2678, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(1470, 1470, 1470))
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addContainerGap(866, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    menuBar.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 1000));
    menuBar.setName("menuBar"); // NOI18N

    fileMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("fileMenu.text")); // NOI18N
    fileMenu.setName("fileMenu"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.ActionMap actionMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(honors231.Honors231App.class).getContext().getActionMap(Honors231View.class, this);
    exitMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("quit")); // NOI18N
    exitMenuItem.setName("exitMenuItem"); // NOI18N
    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);

    helpMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("helpMenu.text")); // NOI18N
    helpMenu.setName("helpMenu"); // NOI18N

    aboutMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("showAboutBox")); // NOI18N
    aboutMenuItem.setName("aboutMenuItem"); // NOI18N
    helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(helpMenu);

    statusPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
    statusPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 800));
    statusPanel.setName("statusPanel"); // NOI18N
    statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 28));

    statusMessageLabel.setName("statusMessageLabel"); // NOI18N

    statusAnimationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
    statusAnimationLabel.setName("statusAnimationLabel"); // NOI18N

    progressBar.setName("progressBar"); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout statusPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(statusPanel);
    statusPanel.setLayout(statusPanelLayout);
    statusPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 830, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    statusPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
                .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
                .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(3, 3, 3))
    );

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Davis\\Desktop\\cs231\\button0.png")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel1.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setName("jLabel1"); // NOI18N

    jFrame1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    jFrame1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1600, 1000));
    jFrame1.setName("jFrame1"); // NOI18N
    jFrame1.setResizable(false);

    jLayeredPane2.setBackground(resourceMap.getColor("jLayeredPane2.background")); // NOI18N
    jLayeredPane2.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    jLayeredPane2.setName("jLayeredPane2"); // NOI18N

    jLabel2.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("jLabel2.icon")); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel2.text")); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setName("jLabel2"); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setBounds(160, 330, 380, 280);
    jLayeredPane2.add(jLabel2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    PC.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("PC.icon")); // NOI18N
    PC.setText(resourceMap.getString("PC.text")); // NOI18N
    PC.setName("PC"); // NOI18N
    PC.setBounds(360, 40, 257, 227);
    jLayeredPane2.add(PC, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    ALU.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("ALU.icon")); // NOI18N
    ALU.setText(resourceMap.getString("ALU.text")); // NOI18N
    ALU.setName("ALU"); // NOI18N
    ALU.setBounds(800, 490, 304, 300);
    jLayeredPane2.add(ALU, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    BC.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("BC.icon")); // NOI18N
    BC.setText(resourceMap.getString("BC.text")); // NOI18N
    BC.setName("BC"); // NOI18N
    BC.setBounds(40, 40, 257, 227);
    jLayeredPane2.add(BC, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    DR.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("DR.icon")); // NOI18N
    DR.setText(resourceMap.getString("DR.text")); // NOI18N
    DR.setName("DR"); // NOI18N
    DR.setBounds(1150, 570, 425, 320);
    jLayeredPane2.add(DR, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    MUXB.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("MUXB.icon")); // NOI18N
    MUXB.setText(resourceMap.getString("MUXB.text")); // NOI18N
    MUXB.setName("MUXB"); // NOI18N
    MUXB.setBounds(1210, 350, 246, 186);
    jLayeredPane2.add(MUXB, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    MUXD.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("MUXD.icon")); // NOI18N
    MUXD.setText(resourceMap.getString("MUXD.text")); // NOI18N
    MUXD.setName("MUXD"); // NOI18N
    MUXD.setBounds(710, 780, 246, 186);
    jLayeredPane2.add(MUXD, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    RF.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("RF.icon")); // NOI18N
    RF.setText(resourceMap.getString("RF.text")); // NOI18N
    RF.setName("RF"); // NOI18N
    RF.setBounds(930, 0, 450, 330);
    jLayeredPane2.add(RF, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    IR.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("IR.icon")); // NOI18N
    IR.setText(resourceMap.getString("IR.text")); // NOI18N
    IR.setName("IR"); // NOI18N
    IR.setBounds(460, 340, 300, 330);
    jLayeredPane2.add(IR, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    ID.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("ID.icon")); // NOI18N
    ID.setText(resourceMap.getString("ID.text")); // NOI18N
    ID.setName("ID"); // NOI18N
    ID.setBounds(100, 670, 500, 227);
    jLayeredPane2.add(ID, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    bg.setIcon(resourceMap.getIcon("bg.icon")); // NOI18N
    bg.setText(resourceMap.getString("bg.text")); // NOI18N
    bg.setName("bg"); // NOI18N
    bg.setBounds(0, 0, 1600, 1000);
    jLayeredPane2.add(bg, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
    jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
    jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLayeredPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1600, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(1714, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLayeredPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1002, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(869, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    setComponent(mainPanel);
    setMenuBar(menuBar);
    setStatusBar(statusPanel);
}// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: Hmmm... I had a very similar problem a few days ago with some menu items not displaying that I resolved the same way.  I wonder if they're related some how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running a clean and build (Run > Clean and Build Main Project). The NetBeans ant scripts do not track the fact that your class file has a dependency on the resource files, so when the class is compiled, it is copied to build/classes (and from there to the jar), but the resources are not.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I thought I tried that before(I guess I hit only the Build button).

Comment: This was the same issue I was having with the menus.  The IDE-generated menus use text stored in resource files as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason: `Invalid Image path`... 
Please use path relative to your project folder. (IDE may caches the image)

Instead of specifying full path:

```
Ex : c:/User/Project/Myapp/src/apple.png
```

Use relative path to paticular class file:

```
Ex : src/apple.png
```